# Stop customers and subscribers from login to dashboard

Tags: login, dashboard

why do subscribers have the ability to log directly into the dashboard? And how do you stop that from happening?

Answer (score 0):

There are a few plugins that'll limit this, including https://wordpress.org/plugins/remove-dashboard-access-for-non-admins/

Comment: The website developer said, "I have done this already" but subscribers are still login into there profiles instead on directly to the website

Comment: How about hiding the dashboard, by changing the URL?

Comment: I don't know if it was done correctly but they said it was done.

Comment: it baffles me that WP made a Login program that allows subscribers and customers to have access to the dashboard and login options